# is there a programmatic way using APEX to define approval process on OpportunityLineItem or OpportunityProduct

Tags: approval-process

I am getting following error. Any help is appreciated

> EXCEPTION_THROWN|[12]|System.DmlException: Process failed. First
>   exception on row 0; first error: NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS, No applicable
>   approval process was found.: []

Answer (score 1):

Approval process can only be defined on Opportunity, not on its line items.

You cannot define any approval processes through code, rather you can use them to submit your request from code.